# Refer to attribute of current record in SpatiaLite trigger function

Tags: qgis, spatialite

This is my first attempt at creating a trigger, so apologies if its obvious.

In QGIS 3.14, I have two SpatiaLite layers [Tree] and [Crown].
I am trying to create a trigger to insert a record into [Crown] after_insert on tree. I want the crown to be a buffer of size [spread], which is an attribute of [Tree] on the geometry of the [Tree].

Currently I have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_crown AFTER INSERT ON Tree
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Crown (treeid, amenity, geometry) 
SELECT uuid, amenity, buffer(geometry,spread) from Tree; 
END
```

But this creates a new crown for every record in Tree. Not just the record created (/inserted)

How do I restrict this to use only the record (tuple) from Trees that is being inserted.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the **NEW** key word.

### Example

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER insert_crown AFTER INSERT ON Tree
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Crown (treeid, amenity, geometry) 
SELECT uuid, amenity, buffer(geometry,spread) from Tree
WHERE uuid = NEW.uuid; 
END
```

or you can do :

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER insert_crown AFTER INSERT ON Tree
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Crown (treeid, amenity, geometry) 
VALUES (NEW.uuid, NEW.amenity, buffer(NEW.geometry,NEW.spread));
END
```

### Documentation

[Sqlite trigger documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

Comment: Many thanks lejedi76